# Proof of $g^a \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$ and $g^b \equiv 1 \pmod{m} \quad \implies \quad g^{\gcd(a,b)} \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

I am trying to understand the following: 
$$g^a \equiv 1 \pmod m \quad \text{and} \quad g^b \equiv 1 \pmod{m}
\quad \implies \quad g^{\gcd(a,b)} \equiv 1 \pmod{m}.$$

I have tried a few approaches, but I can't seem to find one that works out.

Comment: Which approaches have you tried? If we know that, we can prod you better in the right direction.

Comment: letting $d$ be the gcd($a$,$b$), then splitting $g^a$ into $\left(g^d\right)^{a'}$ s.t. $a = d\cdot a'$. Then trying to use $g^d$ as the modular multiplicative inverse of $g^{a' - 1}$, and simplifying down that way.

Comment: Well... What's the big, huge theorem about $\gcd$s that is used all the time?

Comment: $a\cdot u + b\cdot v = 1$ iff gcd($a$,$b$)=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Bézout's identity, there exists a pair of integers $(p,q)$ such that $p a+q b=\gcd(a,b)$.

We then get the following:

> $g^{\gcd(a,b)}=g^{pa+qb}=(g^a)^p\cdot (g^b)^q \equiv 1^p \cdot 1^q\equiv 1 \pmod{m}$

**EDIT:**
There is also the following straight forward argument if you don't know of Bézout's theorem:

> Write $\gcd(a,b)=d$ so that $a=d \alpha$, $b=d\beta$, and $\alpha \perp \beta$.
>
> Let $x$ be the order of the element $g^d=s$ in the group, then we get $s^x\equiv s^{\alpha} \equiv s^{\beta} \pmod{m}$.
>
> Let $\alpha \equiv r_1 \pmod{x}$, $\beta \equiv r_2 \pmod{x}$ where $0\leq r_1,r_2<x$. Then $r_1$ and $r_2$ must both be equal to $0$, because if not, we get $s^{\alpha} \equiv s^{r_1}\equiv 1 \pmod{m}$, which contradicts the fact that $x$ is the order of $s$ (same argument for $r_2$).
>
> Since $x$ divides the two coprime numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$, $x$ must be equal to $1$, and so: $g^d=s^1\equiv 1 \pmod{m}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Let $c$ be the smallest positive integer so that $g^c\equiv 1 \pmod m$.

You can prove that if $g^d \equiv 1 \pmod m$ then $c|d$.

> Use integer division of $d$ by $c$: $d = qc+r$ with $0 \leq r < c$. Since $g^d \equiv g^c \equiv 1 \pmod m$ then $g^{d-qc} \equiv 1 \Rightarrow g^r \equiv 1$ but $c$ was the smallest positive number so that $g^c \equiv 1$, therefore $r = 0$.

That would mean that $c|a$ and $c|b$, so $c|\gcd(a,b)$, and therefore $g^{\gcd(a,b)} \equiv g^{ck} \equiv 1^k \equiv 1\pmod m$